# Objeto criado dentro de condicional If gera erro de compilação c++

Tags: c++, codeblocks

Estou tendo problemas para compilar um programa C++ na IDE Code::Blocks. O que estou tentando fazer é acessar um objeto que foi instanciado dentro de um condicional If. Vou colocar abaixo os códigos do programa principal e também das classes que criei.

Classe Utilizador (classe pai de Aluno e Professor):

```
#ifndef UTILIZADOR_H
#define UTILIZADOR_H
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Utilizador{

private:
    string name;
    int access_level;

public:

    //Setters
    void setName(string name);
    void setAccessLevel(int level);

    //Getters
    string getName();
    int getAccessLevel();
};

#endif // UTILIZADOR_H
```

Classe Professor herda de Utilizador:

```
#ifndef PROFESSOR_H
#define PROFESSOR_H
#include <string>
#include "Utilizador.h"

using namespace std;

class Professor : public Utilizador{

private:

public:
    //Constructor Method
    Professor(string name);

};

#endif // PROFESSOR_H
```

Classe Aluno herda de Utilizador:

```
#ifndef ALUNO_H
#define ALUNO_H
#include <string>
#include "Utilizador.h"

using namespace std;

class Aluno : public Utilizador{

private:
    double *nota = new double; //Store an array of data with the scholar grades of the student during the year
public:
    //Constructor method
    Aluno(string name);

};

#endif // ALUNO_H
```

Abaixo o código do programa principal, onde tento implementar o objeto:

```
#include <iostream> //Input and Output library
#include <windows.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include "include/Aluno.h"
#include "include/Professor.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //Below, this variables have the function of receive the input of data
    string nome;
    int nivel;

    //First contact with the user, request data entry
    cout << "Bem vindo ao programa de operacoes matematicas, vamos comecar!\n\n";
    cout << "Informe seu nome: ";
    cin >> nome; cout << endl;
    cout << "Agora informe qual o seu tipo de utilizador para poder oferecer-mos a melhor experiencia. (1) Professor / (2) Aluno: ";
    cin >> nivel; cout << endl;

    //Creating the object depending of the data that the user inserted in previous step
    if(nivel == 1){
        Professor *a = new Professor(nome);
        a->setAccessLevel(nivel);
    }else{
        Aluno *a = new Aluno(nome);
        a->setAccessLevel(nivel);
    }

    cout << a->getName(); //Linha que consta o erro de Compilação!

    return 0;
}
```

No código do programa principal dá para observar que eu crio o objeto dependendo do nível do usuário por isso o faço dentro do condicional `if`, mas na hora de compilar e executar o programa o Code::Blocks informa o seguinte:

> "error: 'a' was not declared in this scope".

Não entendi o motivo dele não reconhecer que o objeto será de qualquer forma instanciado na variável `a`.

Se eu crio o objeto fora do condicional funciona tranquilamente quando tento acessar os métodos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está tentando utilizar a variável `a` fora do seu escopo. O escopo de uma variável local é somente entre o colchetes de abertura `{` e fechamento `}` de um bloco, iniciando na sua declaração em diante.

```
if(nivel == 1){
    Professor *a = new Professor(nome); // escopo inicia
    a->setAccessLevel(nivel);
} // escopo termina
// 'a' não está disponível aqui
```

da mesma forma

```
else{
    Aluno *a = new Aluno(nome); // escopo inicia
    a->setAccessLevel(nivel);
} // escopo termina
// 'a' não está disponível aqui
```

Para resolver o seu problema, dois pontos:

1. Você deve mover a declaração da sua variável para o mesmo nível de escopo da linha que possui o código `cout << a->getName();`. Dessa maneira, esse código vai ter acesso à variável requisitada.
2. Ao invés de dois ponteiros para cada uma das classes derivada, você deve ter apenas um ponteiro que aponte para a classe base. Dentro dos condicionais, você então aloca memória dinamicamente para uma das classes derivadas.

Com as mudanças:

```
int main()
{
    Utilizador *a;
    // ...
    // Creating the object depending of the data that the user inserted in previous step
    if (nivel == 1) {
        a = new Professor(nome);
    } else {
        a = new Aluno(nome);
    }

    a->setAccessLevel(nivel);
    cout << a->getName();
}
```